# How to download pdf from database using Xamarin and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in Xamarin form which you can see in the screenshot here:

[image]

and this is my database structure:

[image]

In my listview, I have data with button; when the user clicks on download button, a PDF file should be downloaded from the database based on id.

This is my xaml code

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="12,6">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       FontSize="24" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Department}"  
                       FontSize="18" 
                       Opacity="0.6"
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"/>
                <Button Text="Download"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: is the database local or remote?  Is the PDF local or remote?

Comment: i have local database, i am connecting my database by webservice but in local iis

Comment: then it's a remote db from the mobile client's POV.  Where is the PDF actually stored?  What you have in the DB is just the path.  You will need to build a url to the PDF location and have it exposed on a server so that is downloadable.

Comment: i have folder "pdf" in solution explorer of web service where i am saving pdf files

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Text="Download" Clicked="ShowPDF" CommandParameter="{Binding path}"> </Button>

protected void ShowPDF(object sender, EventArgs args) {

  Button button = (Button)sender;

  string path = button.CommandParameter;

  string url = "http://myserver.tld" + path;

  Navigation.PushAsync(new PDFView(url));
}
```

You will need to create a PDFView page that contains a WebView, pass the url to the WebView to display the PDF.

Comment: i have implemented as you said but i am not getting anything in webview. **PDFVIEW.xaml code**
`<StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <WebView x:Name="browser" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="500"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>`  **PDFVIEW.xaml.cs code**
`public partial class PDFView : ContentPage
 {
  public PDFView (string url)
  {
          
   InitializeComponent ();

            browser.Source = url;
        }
 }`